# is possible using query assocation model in sequelize datatype virtual ?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

the code example like this :

```
var Model1 = sequelize.define('Model1', {
    field1: DataTypes.STRING,
    field2: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field3: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      include : {model : Model2},
      get: function() {
        return this.Model2 where : { condition }    <-------------
      }
    }
  })
```

i want to get data on association model,  but filtered first and keep on dataType virtual

Comment: Adding junk to your question is _not_ the proper way to promote it. Please review https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer